# Autobinding in MVC4 WebApi with Ninject.Extensions.Conventions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject

In my MVC4 app I'm using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions to autobind all itnerfaces with their implementation using default mechanism:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
            .FromAssembliesMatching("*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .BindDefaultInterface());
```

This works great for regular controllers, but doesn't for WebApi controllers. What do I need to change/add?

Comment: It should work also for web api controllers. Have you set up dependency resolver for webapi e.g with setting `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`? What error do you get? Which Ninject version are you using?

Comment: Hi Nemesv. I have a mvc4 project with the latest version of nuget package Ninject.Mvc3 installed. The only change I've done so far was pasting the code above into the  RegisterServices method in NinjectWebCommon file. This made DI work for regular controllers, but not for Api ones.
The error I'm getting is: Type 'MyNamespace.TestController' does not have a default constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I resolved the issue by following this article:
http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/06/19/adding-ninject-to-web-api/

In short: I created my own dependency resolver (as per article) and assigned it to GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver as suggested by nemesv

Answer (score 0):

There are already a many examples on how to integrate NInject with Web API through the web, using:

- DependencyResolver

  On ASP.NET website is shown standart way of integration of any DI/IoC with Web API:
  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver
- IDependencyResolver.

  WebApiContrib project shows how to do it with IDependencyResolver
  https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject

Please post more information about your implementation of these resolvers, to be more specific in answer.